# Symfony5 Embedded Form Collection Not Validating

Tags: php, symfony

Env : symfony 5.3.10 / php 8.0

I need to submit a specific form, with multiple levels (no match with my entities) so i created Models with Collections, and one formType per Model

My main model "FirstModel" is validated, but models included in the collection are not. validated. I can add an empty or null label, no validation is done when my form is submitted (no specific validatio group)

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Test;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class FirstModel
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private ?string $numero = null;

    /**
     * @Assert\All({
     *     @Assert\Type(type="App\Model\Test\SecondModel")
     * })
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private Collection $listItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->listItems= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getNumero(): ?string
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $numero
     */
    public function setNumero(?string $numero): void
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;
    }

    

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getListItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->listItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $listItems
     */
    public function setListItems(Collection $listItems): void
    {
        $this->listItems= $listItems;
    }

    public function addListItem(SecondModel $secondModel): void
    {
        if (!$this->listItems->contains($secondModel)) {
            $this->listItems[] = $secondModel;
        }
    }

    public function removeListItem(SecondModel $secondModel): void
    {
        if ($this->listItems->contains($secondModel)) {
            $this->listItems->removeElement($secondModel);
        }
    }    
}
```

SecondModel :

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Test;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SecondModel
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private ?string $label= null;

    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    public function setLabel(?string $label): void
    {
        $this->label= $label;
    }
}
```

First formType :

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Test;

use App\Model\Test\FirstModel;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid;

class FirstModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('numero', TextType::class)
            ->add(
                'listItems',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'entry_type' => SecondModelType::class,
                    'constraints' => array(new Valid())
                ])
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FirstModel::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Second FormType

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Test;

use App\Model\Test\SecondModel;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SecondModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SecondModel::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have a typo in your FirstModelType class, `->add('listeItems',`  instead of `->add('listItems'`.

Comment: just because it is not the real code, I made a mistake rewriting it. original post corrected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem

There was an error in my file wich is not in my example.

i missed a "*", originaly i had :

```
/*
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
```

Sorry